# Exporting members of all DLs in an OU

Tags: exchange-2003, export

I'm trying to export all the members of all the DLs within an OU (either to a single file that's categorized or individual files).

I tried to use:

```
csvde -f "C:\Documents and Settings\root\Desktop\AD Export\DL Export\DL.txt" -r "OU=DLs,OU=Personnel,DC=csi,DC=org" -l "cn,mail"
```

but that only works for individual DLs and there are a lot to input each time.

Any help on getting this done in the most efficient pattern would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I grabbed this PS script online somewhere earlier this year to do something similar.  Hope it helps.  I can't give credit to who created it since it isn't in the script and I can't remember where I found it at this point.

```
$saveto = "C:\\listmembers.txt"

Get-DistributionGroup | sort name | ForEach-Object {

    "`r`n$($_.Name)`r`n=============" | Add-Content $saveto
    Get-DistributionGroupMember $_ | sort Name | ForEach-Object {
        If($_.RecipientType -eq "UserMailbox")
            {
                $_.Name + " (" + $_.PrimarySMTPAddress + ")" | Add-Content $saveto
            }
    }
}
```